# Grok pattern for log files

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am very new to Logstash and ELK in general.
I need to write a grok pattern for a log file in the following format :

```
[191114|16:51:13.577|BPDM|MDS|2|209|ERROR|39999]Interrupted by a signal!!!
```

I tried to write a grok pattern by referring [grok-patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) and by trying out my implementation in [grok-debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), but it didn't work.

```
grok {
match => { "message" => "%{NONNEGINT:fixed}|%{HOSTNAME:host}|%{WORD:word1}|%{WORD:word2}|%{NONNEGINT:num1}|%{NONNEGINT:num2}|%{ERROR|INFO|EVENT}|%{NONNEGINT:num1}|%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the brackets and the pipes, and your second field is not a host, it is a time.

This one works, just validate the field names.

```
\[%{NONNEGINT:fixed}\|%{DATA:time}\|%{WORD:word1}\|%{WORD:word2}\|%{NONNEGINT:num1}\|%{NONNEGINT:num2}\|%{WORD:loglevel}\|%{NONNEGINT:num3}\]%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

This grok will parse your message like this.

```
{
  "word1": "BPDM",
  "word2": "MDS",
  "message": "Interrupted by a signal!!!",
  "loglevel": "ERROR",
  "num1": "2",
  "fixed": "191114",
  "time": "16:51:13.577",
  "num3": "39999",
  "num2": "209"
}
```

Comment: You just need to try the grok pattern in the grok debugger site, not the grok filter block. Try with the pattern in the answer, just checked and it works both in grok debugger and in the grok debbuger inside kibana.